# converting multiple selection to json data and then binding it to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring

How to convert multiple selection to json and bind it to scope? please help me with this.

this is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);

    app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.list = [];
            $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';
            $scope.submit = function() {

                var formData = {

                        "amenities" : $scope.amenities,

                };

                var response = $http.post('/property', formData);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);


                });
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
                });

                //Empty list data after process
                $scope.list = [];
                 $scope.$setPristine();

            };
        }]);
</script>
```

this is multiple selection I'm using :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            Amenities&nbsp; <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="bottom"
                                title="Press Ctrl key to select multiple Amenities"><img
                                src="<c:url value="/resources/images/info-icon.png"/>" /></a>


                                <!--  <select name="amenities" class="form-control" id="property_status" onchange="setDyna()" required> -->
                                <select name="amenities" class="form-control" id="amenities"
                                    onchange="setDyna()" data-ng-model="amenities" multiple>
                                    <option value="pool">Swimming Pool</option>
                                    <option value="park">Playground/park</option>
                                    <option value="gym">Gym/Fitness Center</option>
                                    <option value="security">Gate Security</option>
                                    <option value="club">Club House</option>
                                    <option value="intercom">Intercom</option>
                                    <option value="parking">Visitor Parking</option>
                                    <option value="lift">Lift</option>

                                </select>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Show us your `setDyna` function...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Saurabh Tiwari. setDyna() is useless.. it is empty function.. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: I haven't worked with multiple select but I think you should implement `setDyna` function to retrieve the `ng-model ` values and then you can play with those values however you wish.